# Friendly Way to Handle Potentially Dangerous Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm after a friendly way to handle **A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected**

I want to be able to validate it myself and return my own validation message.

I was thinking of using the [AllowHtml] attribute then checking to see if the value contains potentially dangerous content via another ValidateAttribute or using IValidatableObject.

Is there a built in helper to manually validate the property's value?
Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `[AllowHtml]` together with another validation like that:

```
[AllowHtml]
[RegularExpression("(\<[a-zA-Z\!\/\?]|&#|script\s*\:)", ErrorMessage = "Invalid characters or whatever your message is")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

See [Security Extensibility in MVC4 document](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-63-56/1145.ASPNET_5F00_4_5F00_SecurityExtensibility.pdf) for more info. Hope it helps!

Comment: That's kinda what I said in my question lol Do you know if there is any built in validation helper to check for potentially dangerous values?

Comment: Haven't found the actual implementation. But [the document](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-63-56/1145.ASPNET_5F00_4_5F00_SecurityExtensibility.pdf) says that it checks for 1) The character "<" followed by any of these: 'a-z' or 'A-Z'; '!'; '/'; '?'. 2) The character "&" followed by the character "#". 3) The word "script" followed by a colon (:), potentially with whitespace between them. So I'm updating the answer with this.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you've put into this answer and especially for referencing that security document. I'll most likely go down this route.